# How to check if command line argument is file or not in python?

Tags: python, linux, command, arguments

I want to give input as

```
%>Python_script_name listed_files
```

How to check if  exist as file or it is  some input argument.

```
<listed file can also be in path /govr/rest/listed_files >
```

Please share the small script, by which I can check if command line argument is valid file or it is a simple variable to be processed.

Just to summarize, I need to process my script so as to take  or a single argument at command line.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short and simple Answer.

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile(fname)
```

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure, how to handle command line argument in it.  Please help me with command line arguments usage for file checking.

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure, how to handle command line argument in it.